# Deleting array error

Tags: c++, arrays, delete-operator

So I have the following class method (will probably add more if requested):

EDIT 1:
Here is where paObject gets initialized and how it remains until it reaches `setCapacity(int c)`

```
template <Object>
ArrayClass<Object>::ArrayClass()
{
    _size = 0; //default in case allocation fails
    paObject = new Object[ARRAY_CLASS_DEFAULT_SIZE];
    if (paObject == NULL)
        throw Exception();
    _size = ARRAY_CLASS_DEFAULT_SIZE;
}
```

It may be important to note that my class Vector extends (or whatever it is in c++) `ArrayClass`: `class MyVector: virtual public ArrayClass<Object>{}` and then later on in

```
template <class Object>
MyVector<Object>::MyVector() : ArrayClass<Object>()
{
    _currSize = 0;
    _incFactor = 5;
}
```

it forces to call the ArrayClass constructor.

```
    template <Object >    
    void MyVector<Object>::setCapacity(int c)
    {
        int len = _currSize;
        if (len > c) len = c;
        Object* paNew = new Object[c];
        if (paNew == NULL) throw Exception();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            paNew[i] = paObject[i];
        if (paObject != NULL)
            delete[] paObject;
        paObject = paNew;
        _size = c;
        if (_currSize > len)
            _currSize = len;
    }
```

When the error happens, the value of c is `6` and the value of _currSize (a class private int variable) is `1`. It is also remarkable to remark that paObject is a class pointer of type Object (which is a template... etc. etc.) initialized with an array of Objects of size 1 by the time the error happens (`Object* paObject = new Object[1]`).

Everything executes fine up until it reaches the line `delete[] paObject;` at which point it gives me a `Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)` error.

I seriously don't understand what is wrong.
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just one quick point, that isn't a valid template specialization unless you've included `template<>` in front of it (although some compilers will accept it)

Comment: The `throw Exception();` will never be reached since `new` throws an exception on error and does not return null.

Comment: @Dani Very true, worth using `new nothrow Object[c]` which would return NULL, me beef is that we can't see the declaration of paObject[] here.

Comment: Just eddited the code to include what it was missing. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when you have a heap problem.
Something like:

```
int *a = new char[1];
a[500] = 0;
```

then later, on totally unrelated object you will get an error on `delete` or `new`.

Comment: @Yokhen: it will execute fine, but the program will enter undefined behavior, resulting later in the error you saw.

Comment: @Yokhen, it doesn't, he's showing an example of the error, adn how it may be caused.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us where paObject is declared ... or where it's (re)initialized ...

... but that's almost certainly the problem.

If you haven't initialized it to NULL, it might contain random garbage.  In which case it won't evaluate to NULL, and Bad Things will happen.

Similarly, if don't explicitly reset it to NULL, then Bad Things will also happen.

Of course, we don't even know if paObject is an array (allocated with "new []") ... because you haven't shown us.

BOTTOM LINE:

1) Make sure paObject is initialized before you use it, and correctly initialized before you re-use it.

2) If you treat it as an array object, make sure it's initialized as an array object

3) You also need to be careful about the differences between "Object", "Object references" (&Object or Object *), arrays of Objects.  In particular, you need to consider when you're passing a reference to an existing object, or when you're (perhaps unintentially) creating a new object.

These links should help:

- http://cplus.about.com/od/learning1/ss/constructors.htm
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_copy_constructor.htm

==================================================================

ADDENDUM:

It sounds like the error `Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)` is occurring because you're overwriting your array.

```
Object* paObject = new Object[1]  // This is really easy to overwrite!
```

I don't see *where* in the code you're writing to paObject (or writing to some alias of paObject), but I'm almost certain that's the problem.

IMHO...